# How to add label to edges in d3 graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Please see
http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

It shows some nodes and the edges between them. Can you tell what code to add in that and where so that the edges have labels. You can assume any suitable location for the labels and you can also assume any label text.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add labels just as you add the paths for the links themselves. All you need to do is calculate the position according to the positions of the two nodes the link connects. The code would look something like this.

```
svg.selectAll("text").data(links).enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x)/2; })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y)/2; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.something; });
```

Note that in your `tick` function, you would also need to update the position of the labels.

Comment: I wrote that code just above tick() function i.e. globally, inside tick function, and inside Restart function (just before calling force.start). But somehow I am not seeing any label text. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My complete code is too long but it is based on the javascript code in
http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

So could u please tell where to put your solution in http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347  ?

I am trying to see if I can extract some relevant part of my code.

Comment: Just to test, I changed d.something in your answer to d.source.id

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Did you have a look at any of the other questions that deal with labels in force directed graphs?

Comment: Sorry. Now it works. I am using svg.selectAll("link") and used hardcoded label text. That makes it work. Somehow d.source.id is not printing anything although not giving any error too, although every node has an id, which I am displaying inside the node. Anyway, I am seeing why. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh, another big problem. I am updating the position of the label inside tick(). The label remains at previous position and also appears at new label, so the text is unclear. Could you tell me how to remove the text from the old position?

Comment: Instead of appending, adjust the position attributes in the same way as for the nodes and links.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff - I have a similar situation where I need to place labels on edges but the edges are not necessarily strait lines and can be curved. is there a built in way to place them to avoid overlapping?

Comment: @Ace not as far as I know.