# How to add text labels on edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, force-layout, directed-graph

Guys i am following this example in my application http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347 and want to show text on edges but so far didn't get success. Can any one please guide me with code on how to put text on edges for this specific example.

```
this.path = this.svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path')
this.path = this.path.data(uncollapsedLinks);
    this.path.classed('selected', function (d) { return d === this.selected_link; })
        .style('marker-start', function (d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : ''; })
        .style('marker-end', function (d) { return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : ''; });


    // add new links
    this.path.enter()
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr('class', 'link')
        .classed('selected', function (d) { return d === this.selected_link; })
        .style('marker-start', function (d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : ''; })
        .style('marker-end', function (d) { return d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : ''; })


    var edgelabels = this.svg.selectAll(".link")
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr({
            'class': 'edgelabel',
            'id': function (d, i) { return 'edgelabel' + i },
            'font-size': 10,
            'fill': '#aaa'
        })
        .attr("dx", 20)
        .attr("dy", 0)
        .append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#edgepath' + i })
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function (d, i) { return 'label ' + i });
```

Comment: Add some examples of what you have tried and didn't work, maybe we can help you from there.

Comment: @Vicenç Gascó updated with code!!!

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344504/how-to-add-label-to-edges-in-d3-graph#